# Scala Play form mapping and validation

Tags: validation, scala, playframework, mapping

I'm creating some system, that can accept different incoming JSONs with ~40 fields inside. But as you may know, Play form mapping, can accept up to 18 field maximum.

So I thought it could be a good idea to split these incoming fields in to groups. For example Group1, Group2.. Group8. So I would accept only 8 parameters inside each group and these groups will have their own form mappings (where all fields are optional). 
It was ok, until I came to the point: for some form mappings (for case classes) these fields must be mandatory. 
For example, FormMapping1 must have Group1.field1, if not - form should give an validation error. But FormMapping2 can ignore Group1.field1, but Group2.field2 is mandatory for it. 
But how should I create Group1 form mapping then?

As Forms do convert JSONs to objects, it's hard for me to imagine, how can I even do this validation. I mean, my case classes should have different constructor for each case I'm having mandatory field?

I hope I've described the situation well. 
Would be great to hear from you some strategies of dealing with such issues. As I suppose my strategy isn't the best.
Thanks in advance!

P.S. currently I'm thinking about move away from Play Form validation to other.

Comment: See [JSON Reads/Writes/Format Combinators](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonCombinators)

Comment: Documentation was the first place I went :) So at the end, what I come up with: I have created a separate Form mappings for each group. And for each event I receive in the application I have different group combination. For each group, which has additional validation (like mandatory fields), I have added verifying statements, which do the check.

Comment: You can parse yourself json string :) - `def action() = Action(parse.json) { request =>
val productJson = request.body; your code here }`